# Why do these binary representations yield the same number?

Tags: javascript, binary, ieee-754

According to the documentation, one can convert a binary representation of a number to the number itself using [parseInt(string, base)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

For instance,

```
var number = parseInt("10100", 2);
// number is 20
```

However, take a look at the next example:

```
var number = parseInt("1000110011000011101000010100000110011110010111111100011010000", 2);
// number is 1267891011121314000

var number = parseInt("1000110011000011101000010100000110011110010111111100100000000", 2);
// number is 1267891011121314000
```

How is this possible?

Note that the binary numbers are almost the same, except for the last 9 bits.

Comment: keywords to google: ieee754, floating point precision.

Answer (score 2):

1267891011121314000 is way over `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991). It can't safely represent it in memory.

Take a look at this classic example:

```
1267891011121314000 == 1267891011121314001  // true
```

Comment: I'd go from the other side: `1000110011000011101000010100000110011110010111111100011010000` is longer than 52 bits.

Comment: @zerkms For details we will have to go into the specification for `parseInt`.

Comment: It's not about details of `parseInt`, but IEEE754.

Comment: The standard declares ES numbers to be IEEE754 double precision numbers (and we should not care how it is implemented internally, externally it must follow the mentioned standard semantics). "In fact, parseInt specifically maps values to [-2^31, 2^31 -1]" --- that is surely not true

Answer (score 1):

Because that's a 61-bit number and the highest-precision type that Javascript will store is a 64-bit floating point values (using [IEEE-754 doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).

A 64-bit float does not have 61 bits of integral precision, since the 64 bits used [are split into the fraction and exponent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) As you can see from the graphic of the bit layout, only 52 bits are available to the mantissa (or fraction), which is used when storing an integer.

Many bignum libraries exist to solve this sort of thing, as it's a very common problem in scientific applications. They tend not to be as fast as math with hardware support, but allow much more precision. Pulling from Github results, [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) may be what you need to support these values.

Comment: Well, the first phrase must be rephrased. I'm wrong with it being "incorrect", but it is extremely misleading. `parseInt` produces integers, it is more about 52 bits of a fraction, other than 64bits overall.

Comment: @zerkms that's what I was getting at. Rephrased to be more clear.

Comment: If you mention the magic "52 bits" somewhere it would make me the happiest cat of the day :-) (upvoted anyway)

Answer (score 0):

There are upper and lower limits on numbers in JavaScript. JavaScript represents number as 64 bit floating point. IEEE754

Look into a BigDecimal implementation in JavaScript if you need larger support.